# MediaWiki Portal Creation

Tags: mediawiki

Link to the site with the issue is [here](http://wiki.phantomworkshop.com/index.php?title=Portal%3aPhantom_Jump).

It looks like I got the portal created correctly. The instructions for this on mediawiki seem better than on wikipedia. What I don't get is why the link in the box adds this "Template:"
to the fullpagename. It makes it so the edit button does not go the the page that contains the content for the box.

Followed instructions [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Portals) on portal creation.
Got the portal templates from [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Portals/Templates).

In box is Template:Portal:Phantom Jump/Intro, it should be Portal:Phantom Jump/Intro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `{{{{FULLPAGENAME}}/Intro}}` is transformed into `{{Portal:Phantom Jump/Intro}}`, which is understood as “transclude the *template* `Portal:Phantom Jump/Intro`”, since most of the time, when transcluding, you do want to tranclude a template. If that's not what you want, you need to override that using `:`: `{{:{{FULLPAGENAME}}/Intro}}` will transclude the *page* `Portal:Phantom Jump/Intro`.

Comment: Dude you are awesome! I've been beating my head against the wall for 3 days now.